# "RuntimeError: a view of a leaf Variable that requires grad is being used in an in-place operation" when there's actually no in-place operations

Tags: python, pytorch

I am working on some paper replication, but I am having trouble with it.

According to the log, it says that `RuntimeError: a view of a leaf Variable that requires grad is being used in an in-place operation.` However, when I check the line where the error is referring to, it was just a simple property setter inside the class:

```
@pdfvec.setter
def pdfvec(self, value):
   self.param.pdfvec[self.key] = value   # where the error message is referring to
```

Isn't in-place operations are something like `+=` or `*=` etc.? I don't see why this error message appeared in this line.

I am really confused about this message, and I will be glad if any one knows any possible reason this can happen.

For additional information, this is the part where the setter function was called:

```
def _update_params(params, pdfvecs):
    idx = 0
    for param in params:
        totdim = param.stats.numel()
        shape = param.stats.shape
        param.pdfvec = pdfvecs[idx: idx + totdim].reshape(shape)   # where the setter function was called
        idx += totdim
```

I know this can still lack information for solving the problem, but if you know any possiblity why the error message appeared I would be really glad to hear.

Comment: Even variable assignment into a leaf variable that requires grad is considered an in-place operation. Assuming that `self.param.pdfvec[self.key]` is actually a leaf tensor, try doing `self.param.pdfvec[self.key].data = value`

Comment: @OmarAlSuwaidi Thanks! I think it is working now. I am still bit confused how this can be considered as an in-place operation. If you don't mind, could you explain more details about how it is an in-place operation, and why adding `.data` helps the problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In-place operation means the assignment you've done is modifiying the underlying storage of your Tensor, of which `requires_grad` is set to True, according to your error message.

That said, your `param.pdfvec[self.key]` is not a leaf Tensor, because they will be updated during back-propagation. And you tried to assign a value to it , that will interference with autograd, so this action is prohibited by default. You can do this by directly modifying its underlying storage(f.e., with `.data`).